# What happens / should happen when i click "DENY" in cookie consent banner?

Tags: cookies, adsense

I'm developing a web application and i tried to add Adsense. Recently i learned that GDPR & CCPA messages should be displayed to obtain users consent .

So the question is, Should i have to do something in my code when users press "DO NOT CONSENT"
or is it taken care of automatically by Adsense?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have a function to obtain cookies and if a user does not give the consent just skip the function. Nothing more.

Comment: I didnt come across using a function with Adsense. Its more of like enabling and publishing in adsense portal.